# Can not connected to ComosDB for MongoDB (vCore) from Azure Data Factory

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

i try to add Cosmos DB Linked service in Azure Data Factory to copy documents from NoSQL API database to MongoDB API (vCore) database.

In ADF we have default connectors to Cosmos DB NoSQL API but not for MongoDB vCore option. Thats why i decided to go with MongoDB connector.

But when i copy connection string from my CosmosDB and fill gaps:

```
mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@XYZ-cluster.mongocluster.cosmos.azure.com/?tls=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000
```

[image]

It does not work with ADF connector:
[image]

The same connection string works in Azure Data Studio:

[image]

The question is, how to prepare connection string to MongoDB placed in vCore CosmosDB option?

DB and collection is empty

Comment: There is no Cosmos DB MongoDB vCore-specific connector available. Have you tried the native MongoDB connector? Even though Cosmos DB MongoDB vCore isn't really the same as native MongoDB, it should be wire-compatible.

Comment: I use native mongodb connector.  Check my screen

Comment: You may need to adjust the connection string specifically for ADF's MongoDB connector. Ensure that all the parameters in the connection string are compatible with what ADF expects for MongoDB connections. Sometimes, removing certain parameters or adjusting them to match ADF's expected format can resolve these issues.

Comment: Yea good point but i tried a lot of things and i think its not that simple, and i look for a solution. Sounds strange that i can not connect Cosmos DB to ADF, two azure resources that are not compatible togheter